# How to parse HttpServletRequest for curl / wget options?

Tags: java, servlets, curl, httprequest, wget

When a request is done in curl with a user parameter like:

```
 curl -u <user> http://url...
```

how can i get the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `curl` uses HTTP Basic authentication by default, the user and the password are combined using `:` as separator and encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64. You can get the base64-encoded value from the `Authorization` header. The header may looks like `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==`.

See [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-2) for more information.

Comment: so the  Basic string value is the decoded user and password?

Comment: @Gobliins yes, it is.